# What is "currently active slave" in Linux bonding & adaptive load balancing

Tags: bonding

My understanding of adaptive load balancing for NIC bonding was that it would dynamically abuse ARP requests to cause traffic ingress and outgress to come from different slaves to attempt to optimize traffic.

However, a "currently active slave" seems to indicate that it's using the other slaves for failover instead.

In this context, what does "currently active slave" mean?

Answer (score 0):

In the alb bond currently active slave is the slave, whose MAC address is used as HW address of the bond.

From: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt

> A problematic outcome of using ARP        negotiation for balancing is that
>   each time that an         ARP request is broadcast it uses the hardware
>   address       of the bond.  Hence, peers learn the hardware address       of
>   the bond and the balancing of receive traffic         collapses to the
>   current slave.  This is handled by        sending updates (ARP Replies) to
>   all the peers with        their individually assigned hardware address such
>   that      the traffic is redistributed.

Comment: "This is handled by sending updates (ARP Replies) to all the peers with their individually assigned hardware address such that the traffic is redistributed." - This seems to contradict that description. If the bond assigned HW on a per-peer basis, then why would one of them be the "currently active" one?